# Windows RDS add server to use RDS

Tags: windows, rds, windows-server-2022

I hope you can help me with the following problem. I currently have a managementserver in my domain that is used by our helpdesk. We want to migrate the server to 2022. For this I want to allow more than 2 RDP sessions. I already have this working on my old management server. But I can't figure out how to allow more than 2 RDP sessions on my new Management server

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Remote Desktop Session Host role and the Remote Desktop License Server role and you need to purchase and install RDS CAL's.